# What is the difference between hashicorp/precise64 and hashicorp/bionic64?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I found some online tutorial is using `vagrant init hashicorp/bionic64` or `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64` to initialize Vagrant.

I only found these info about these two boxes:

- https://app.vagrantup.com/hashicorp/boxes/bionic64
- https://app.vagrantup.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64

So

- hashicorp/precise64 v1.1.0 is created almost 8 years ago.
- hashicorp/bionic64 v1.0.282 is created over 2 years ago.

What is the real difference between `hashicorp/precise64` and `hashicorp/bionic64`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Ubuntu operating system uses alliterative animal names for each of its major releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). "Precise Pangolin" is the name for Ubuntu 12.04 and "Bionic Beaver" is the name for Ubuntu 18.04.

hashicorp/precise64 is an Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit operating system, and hashicorp/bionic64 is an Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit operating system.